# How can I add external python libraries into HDFS?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Is there any way, how to add external libraries like [this one](https://github.com/mtth/hdfs) into hdfs?
It seems pyspark needs external libs to have them in the shared folder on hdfs. Byt since I am using shellscript, which runs that pyspark script with external libraries, it fails importing them.

See post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369142/importerror-no-module-named-hdfs-ext-kerberos) about ImportError.

Answer (score 2):

You can add external lib with the `--py-files` option. You can provide either a .py file or a .zip.

For exemple, using a spark submit :

```
spark-submit --master yarn --py-files ./hdfs.zip myJob.py
```

Check corresponding documentation : [Submitting Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit)

Answer (score 0):

We installed the library on all working nodes. We had it only on NameNode.